# Custom Post Type Pagination For Genesis Child Theme

Tags: pagination, child-theme, genesis-theme-framework

Is there any possible to implement the pagination for custom post type in ***Genesis*** child theme, I'm using ***Genesis*** : 2.0.2 and ***Wordpress*** version is : 4.0.

I've tried the following code in my template, but it's not working for me.

```
<?php echo genesis_posts_nav(); ?>
```

And my normal category pagination also not working for me in my genesis child theme.

```
<?php echo genesis_posts_nav(); ?>
```

**My Custom Template Code Here :**

```
<?php 

remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'sk_do_loop' );

function sk_do_loop(){

$args_spotlight_latest = array('posts_per_page' => 5,'post_type' => 'spotlight', 'post_status'=>'publish','meta_key' => 'featured_slider','meta_value' => 'true');
$spotlight_posts_latest = new WP_Query($args_spotlight_latest);

/** Content Area **/

if($spotlight_posts_latest->have_posts()){

    while($spotlight_posts_latest->have_posts()){
    $spotlight_posts_latest->the_post();                        
    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id());   

    ..............
    ..............
    ..............
   }

}

genesis_posts_nav();

}

?>
```

Can anyone help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you do not need to add `echo` statement before the function. Code will be `<?php genesis_posts_nav(); ?>` . Are you creating custom template for custom post type? You'll use the genesis_custom_loop() function for custom query and `genesis_posts_nav()` will be automatically called for archive page.

Comment: i have tried in both way both with "echo" statement and without "echo", it's not working for me

Comment: I think that your custom query have problem. Otherwise it will work perfectly. Which theme you are using? Can you share the code for custom post type?

Comment: i've shared my template code, can u have a look on it

Comment: your problem is that you're not fully using the genesis hook. Your're writing custom code in genesis framework. Ok. I am modifying your code. Lets see what is happening.

Comment: question specific to a specific theme are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try this code:

```
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'sk_do_loop' );

function sk_do_loop(){

global $wp_query;
$temp_query = $wp_query;

// Fix for the WordPress 3.0 "paged" bug.
$paged = 1;
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
if ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
$paged = intval( $paged );

$args_spotlight_latest = array('posts_per_page' => 5,'post_type' => 'spotlight', 'post_status'=>'publish','meta_key' => 'featured_slider','meta_value' => 'true', 'paged' => $paged);
$spotlight_posts_latest = new WP_Query($args_spotlight_latest);
$wp_query = $spotlight_posts_latest;
/** Content Area **/

if($spotlight_posts_latest->have_posts()){

    while($spotlight_posts_latest->have_posts()){
    $spotlight_posts_latest->the_post();                        
    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id());   

    ..............
    ..............
    ..............
   }

}

genesis_posts_nav();

wp_reset_query();

}
```

Comment: I've one more doubt, if we have one more pagination in that same page means, how to implement that one ?

Comment: Yes. You can. But I'll highly recommend the **genesis_custom_loop()** function and customize the content by genesis hook.

Comment: Can you share some example codes here for those functionalities, because i'm new to genesis.

Comment: Ok. Here is code http://pastebin.com/3Y1fy0Gf of my one PRO Child. Just check the code & take the concept. Don't use same code. it'll not work for your project. But it'll give you the knowledge about GF. Hope that it'll help you.

Comment: I'm facing one more problem in pagination, can you help me in tht ?